# Iterating through file names in a folder and renaming with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder containing 1000+ files.  They all have a different name format (from very inconsistent name formatting over time), so I can't just use `replace` or `split` in `Python`.  But I do have an Excel sheet with 2 columns

```
ShortName     FullName
Banana 2020   Banana_2020_Fruit.pdf
Apple 900     Apple_900_Fruit_v2.pdf
Pear 1800     Pear 1800_new.pdf
Plum 210      Plum210.pdf
```

How can I just rewrite all file names using the `ShortName` column?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

myfile = pd.read_excel("filetoexcel.xlsx")

for fileName in os.listdir("C:/Users/name/here/folder"):
   os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace(_____))
```

Comment: Have you read the excel sheet into python e.g. do you have the (from, to) pairs in a list, dict etc in python?

Comment: It's fairly common to save your Excel file as a `.csv` to simplify this. There is builtin [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for reading them, which may be easier than the Excel format. It's also literally just a comma-separated file (each row is a new line separated by commas), so you can read it directly `with open()`, though beware that commas in the names of files (you can do a search with Excel before saving) may confound this.

Comment: Have you seen whether reading the excel file into pandas works? `pandas.read_excel("filename.xlsx")`? In that first example, do you want the file to be `"Banana 2020.pdf"`?

Comment: I imported the excel file now. I do not have a dictionary for the lists yet.

Comment: Is FullName the actual FileName and you want to change it to ShortName?

Comment: @pyeR_biz No, FileName is the name of the folder that contains all the files. Then I want to rename every file to the list in ShortName column.

Comment: @DeAnnaMartinez what is 'FullName' column? is it the actual name of a file ?

Comment: @pyeR_biz yes, 'FullName' is the exact name of each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path as path

df = pd.read_excel(file)
df = df.set_index('ShortName')

folder = path('path/to/your/folder')
for file in folder.iterdir():
    shname = file.stem
    fname = df.loc[shname, 'FullName']
    os.rename(file, folder/path(fname))
```

Comment: I get an error ```KeyError: 'first_file_name_here'```  The very first file in my folder is given in that KeyError.

Comment: Did you set the index? Have you printed out file.stem and made sure it's in the ShortName column? Could there be some whitespace (in the filename or the excel table) that you're missing?

Comment: after ```shname = file.stem``` I did ```print(shname)``` and it's showing the FullName column values.

Comment: ```folder: Path``` ```folder is not callable``` on the last line

Comment: Can I just check that the files currently have the 'ShortName', and you want to rewrite them to the 'FullName'?

Comment: the files are currently names with the "FullName" and I want to shorten and change the names to "ShortName".

Comment: In that case swap the "FullName" and "ShortName" strings in the code above.

Comment: That worked! I had to redo it and add ".pdf" to the end of  all "ShortName" files, or  else they wouldn't open up again. @Linden